# Split every line of the document into groups of n

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def ngram(n, k, document):
    f = open(document, 'r')
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        words =  line.split() + line.split()
        print words
    return {}
```

For ex- "I love the Python programming language" and n = 2
are "I love", "love the", "the Python", "Python programming", and "programming langue";

I want to store in a list and then compare how many of them are same.

Comment: what should be the output if `n=3`?

Comment: Check out the `itertools pairwise` recipe: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes and `collections.Counter` data structure: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what you want returned. Assuming one line says:

`I love the Python programming language`

And that you want to do nothing inter-line.

```
from collections import deque
def linesplitter(line, n):
    prev = deque(maxlen=n)       # fixed length list
    for word in line.split():    # iterate through each word
        prev.append(word)        # keep adding to the list
        if len(prev) == n:       # until there are n elements
            print " ".join(prev) # then start printing
                                 # oldest element is removed automatically

with open(document) as f:        # 'r' is implied
    for line in f:
        linesplitter(line, 2)    # or any other length!
```

Output:

```
I love
love the
the Python
Python programming
programming language
```

Answer (score 2):

You could adapt from one of the [itertools recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
import itertools
def ngrams(N, k, filepath):
    with open(filepath) as infile:
        words = (word for line in infile for word in line.split())
        ts = itertools.tee(words, N)
        for i in range(1, len(ts)):
            for t in ts[i:]:
                next(t, None)
        return zip(*ts)
```

With a test file that looks like this:

```
 I love
the
python programming language
```

Here's the output:

```
In [21]: ngrams(2, '', 'blah')
Out[21]: 
[('I', 'love'),
 ('love', 'the'),
 ('the', 'python'),
 ('python', 'programming'),
 ('programming', 'language')]

In [22]: ngrams(3, '', 'blah')
Out[22]: 
[('I', 'love', 'the'),
 ('love', 'the', 'python'),
 ('the', 'python', 'programming'),
 ('python', 'programming', 'language')]
```

Comment: what does the list `answer` do in your code? And the parameter `k` is also not used

Comment: @Smac89: absolutely nothing. It's vestigial code and shouldn't be there. Thanks for catching my error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can achieve this through a List Comprehension:

```
>>> [s1 + " " + s2 for s1, s2 in zip(s.split(), s.split()[1:])]
['I love', 'love the', 'the Python', 'Python programming', 'programming language']
```

You can also use the `str.format` function:

```
>>> ["{} {}".format(s1, s2) for s1, s2 in zip(s.split(), s.split()[1:])]
['I love', 'love the', 'the Python', 'Python programming', 'programming language']
```

The finalized version of the function:

```
from itertools import tee, islice


def ngram(n, s):
    var = [islice(it, i, None) for i, it in enumerate(tee(s.split(), n))]
    return [("{} " * n).format(*itt) for itt in zip(*var)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from splitting import ngram
>>> thing = 'I love the Python programming language'
>>> ngram(2, thing)
['I love ', 'love the ', 'the Python ', 'Python programming ', 'programming language ']
>>> ngram(3, thing)
['I love the ', 'love the Python ', 'the Python programming ', 'Python programming language ']
>>> ngram(4, thing)
['I love the Python ', 'love the Python programming ', 'the Python programming language ']
>>> ngram(1, thing)
['I ', 'love ', 'the ', 'Python ', 'programming ', 'language ']
```

Comment: Parametrizing for n would be difficult here

Comment: What you really want is a solution that uses `itertools.tee`. Check out my post

Comment: @inspectorG4dget used `tee`, but put it all in a list comprehension, I just copied a bit from the `pairwise` function from recepies.

Comment: That works, but you're listifying `it` and taking `[i:]`, which makes it less memory efficient. It would make more sense to `itertools.islice(it)` and THEN listify it. Still, I like your last solution better than the first. +1!

Comment: I think generators are the way to go, like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here a *"one-line"* solution, using **list comprenhension**:

```
s = "I love the Python programming language"

def ngram(s, n):
    return [" ".join(k) for k in zip(*[l[0] for l in zip(s.split()[e:] for e in range(n))])]

# Test
for i in range(1, 7):
    print ngram(s, i)
```

**Output:**

```
['I', 'love', 'the', 'Python', 'programming', 'language']
['I love', 'love the', 'the Python', 'Python programming', 'programming language']
['I love the', 'love the Python', 'the Python programming', 'Python programming language']
['I love the Python', 'love the Python programming', 'the Python programming language']
['I love the Python programming', 'love the Python programming language']
['I love the Python programming language']
```

**Note** That no `k` parameter is needed.

---

Adapted to your case:

```
def ngram(document, n):
    with open(document) as f:
        for line in f:
            print [" ".join(k) for k in zip(*[l[0] for l in zip(line.split()[e:] for e in range(n))])]
```